# Automatic renewal subscription automatically cancels itself after a few minutes. RevenueCat

Tags: swiftui, app-store-connect, revenuecat

I'm using RevenueCat for purchases. After making a payment with Sandbox, the Pro version within my mobile application gets canceled a few minutes later. What could be the reason for this?
Settings -> AppStore -> Sandbox Account -> Manage -> Allow purchases and renewals (active) -> Renewal Rate set to 3 minutes. As seen in the screenshot, it has expired after 3 minutes. Could this be the reason? I will publish the application on the AppStore. I'm afraid of encountering any errors :)

Why do you think it automatically cancels the Pro version within the application? When the application is first opened, I check whether the user has purchased the package or not.

[image]

RevenueCat:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
func checkSubscribe() {
    Task {
        do {
            let customerInfo = try await Purchases.shared.customerInfo()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if customerInfo.entitlements["AI Pro"]?.isActive == true {
                    self.isPro = true
                } else {
                    self.isPro = false
                }
            }
        } catch {
            AnalyticsManager.shared.sendEvent(eventName: "error_checkSubscribe", parameters: ["error":error.localizedDescription])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions in Sandbox in RC cancel after a certain number of renewals, depending on the store. To properly test this use multiple sandbox accounts, and multiple simulators.

[Subscriptions in sandbox cancel automatically after a certain number of renewals (RC Community Thread)](https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/test-subscriptions-always-cancelled-1404)

Also, if the user has opted-out of auto renew, subs are automatically cancelled as expected

I also suggest a read of [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)